# Expected Declaration Error using Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to pass the boolean value of a `UISwitch` to another class using `NSUserDefaults`. For some reason, in the class that contains the switches, the `if` statements that are supposed to set the value to `NSUserDefaults` cannot read the switch declarations.

#### ViewController.swift

```
@IBOutlet var shrimpSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBOutlet var nutSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBOutlet var dairySwitch: UISwitch!

let switchState = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


if shrimpSwitch.switch.on{

    switchState.setBool(true, forKey: "shrimpSwitch")
}
else{

    switchState.setBool(false, forKey: "shrimpSwitch")
}

if nutSwitch.on{

    switchState.setBool(true, forKey: "nutSwitch")
}
else{

    switchState.setBool(false, forKey: "nutSwitch")
}

if dairySwitch.on{

    switchState.setBool(true, forKey: "dairySwitch")
}
else{

    switchState.setBool(false, forKey: "dairySwitch")
}
```

In the first If statement(shrimpSwitch.on), it will say Expected Declaration. Am I declaring the switches all wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that you need to put your code inside a method. All you need is to move it to viewDidLoad() or any other method.