# "Expected Declaration" in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I tried to code a program which has two images. I use 4 buttons UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT to move one image. **If that image reaches the other, a text field will show up: "You are the winner!".**

However, the line containing the code If... always gets "Expected Declaration" error. How can I make it run, pls?

This is the whole code, the names of two images are ConChimCu and Trung:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtBai: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ConChimCu: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Trung: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func Up(sender: AnyObject) {
       ConChimCu.frame.origin.y = ConChimCu.frame.origin.y - 2
   }

    @IBAction func RIGHT(sender: AnyObject) {
        ConChimCu.frame.origin.x = ConChimCu.frame.origin.x + 2
    }

    @IBAction func DOWN(sender: AnyObject) {
        ConChimCu.frame.origin.y = ConChimCu.frame.origin.y + 2
    }

    @IBAction func LEFT(sender: AnyObject) {
        ConChimCu.frame.origin.x = ConChimCu.frame.origin.x - 2
    }

    if ConChimCu.frame.origin.x == Trung.frame.origin.x { txtBai.text = "You are the winner!"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected Declaration Error Xcode 6.2 using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835490/expected-declaration-error-xcode-6-2-using-swift)

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement must be inside a function.

Example

```
    func checkCollision() {
        if ConChimCu.frame.origin.x == Trung.frame.origin.x { 
            txtBai.text = "You are the winner!"
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that's what he needs. Also he should call that function after every move.

Comment: I follow your advice, the error doesnt show up anymore. But when "ConChimCu" reach "Trung", the text "You are the winner" doesnt show up.
I also corrected "func checkCollition()" into "func checkCollision()" but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you do what @EvdzhanMustafa suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you are doing wrong here.

1. You have written IF condition out of the function scope. (As @Kingslayerpy suggested)
2. Even after correction If condition you didn't called it. (As per my understanding according to your comment)

So here is the solution.

create function like

```
func checkCollision() {
    if ConChimCu.frame.origin.x == Trung.frame.origin.x { 
        txtBai.text = "You are the winner!"
    }
}
```

and call it from your every button action.

e.g.

```
@IBAction func Up(sender: AnyObject) {
    ConChimCu.frame.origin.y = ConChimCu.frame.origin.y - 2
    checkCollision()
}
```

Enjoy ;]