# Issue with including NSDateFormatter in a class

Tags: swift, class, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to add time in my Note Class but getting an error message.

[image: http://imgur.com/hyRHj30]

What is the correct way to include time on note entry in a class?

Here are the error message inline commented:

```
class noteTime{
var timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
timeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"  //ERROR: Expected Declaration
timeFormatter.AMSymbol = "AM"
timeFormatter.PMSymbol = "PM"

var timeString = timeFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) 
//ERROR: Instance member 'timeFormatter' cannot be used on type 'noteTime'
}
```

Comment: Aren't you not putting that code into a func?

Comment: @Larme No, I am not. It is in a separate class file. The same code works if I put inside a func...

Comment: You cannot run that code on the top level of the class

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835490/expected-declaration-error-xcode-6-2-using-swift.

Comment: @vadian How do I save time in my class then??

Comment: @MartinR thank you for pointing it out. But, my case is very different. I am trying to declare a class in a separate swift file. How can I put inside a method just to make this code work. There should be another way to write this code inside a class..

Comment: Put the code inside the `init` method.

Comment: What's the purpose of the code? If you want to get a timestamp each time an instance is created use a closure to assign the value, otherwise use computed properties.

Comment: May I also kindly suggest that you spend time reading [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) and learn the basics of Swift.

Comment: @vadian thank you suggesting to use closures. Could you please post the code... The only confusion I have is how to use NSDateFormatter inside a closure.

Comment: @rmaddy I am not sure how `init` will solve this issue. Please post the code you have in mind. As far as I know, `init` is to define what variables are need to initialize an object instance of a class. I don't want to initialize my NSDateFormatter

Comment: @rmaddy And yes, I am new to Swift. Need to read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a timestamp use a closure to assign the value.

```
class NoteTime { // class names are supposed to start with a capital letter

  let timeString : String  = {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    formatter.AMSymbol = "AM"
    formatter.PMSymbol = "PM"
    return formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
  }()
}
```

Now each time an instance is created the timestamp is saved as constant (`let`!) in `timeString`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution (in Swift 3.0):

```
class NoteTime {
    var timeFormatter : DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"

        return formatter
    }()

    var timeString : String {
        get {
            return timeFormatter.string(from: Date())
        }
    }
}
```

This sets up the date formatter one time. And then every time you access the `timeString` property you get the current time formatted as desired.

Comment: Hmm.. That's pretty interesting and advanced.. Thanks for posting the code.. Not useful for me though as I am not using Swift 3. I saw many negative reviews about XCode 8 and Swift 3. Infact, in the Mac App store, someone said not to use XCode 8 if you want to release your app before Christmas.. Anyways, off-topic..

Comment: FYI - the code I posted can easily be converted back to Swift 2. Use `NSDateFormatter` instead of `DateFormatter`. Then fix a few other reasonably obvious references. I just don't have Xcode 7 so I can't verify what changes to make.

Comment: @EcoApps Swift 3 is a great release but requires a bit knowledge of the language and certain hand work to update the projects. I suppose that the *many negative reviews* have been written by people whose poor (or even none) knowledge of Swift is from Youtube tutorials and copy&paste *googled* code. For example rmaddy's code can be simply translated back to Swift 2 by adding `NS` prefix to `Date` and `DateFormatter`, change both *symbol* properties to uppercase (`AMSymbol` and `PMSymbol`) and replace `string(from:` with `stringFromDate(`.