# Create Directory in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am a new student in 9th grade learning **swift**, creating a school project .

I am trying to create a directory where I want to save a scanned file into pdf format.

While creating directory I am getting error below.

Error 1:

> Cannot use instance member 'filemgr' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.

Error 2:

> Expected declaration

Code:

```
let filemgr = FileManager.default


let dirPaths = filemgr.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

let docsURL = dirPaths[0]

let newDir = docsURL.appendingPathComponent("data").path

do{
    try filemgr.createDirectory(atPath: newDir,withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Please assist me in resolving this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected Declaration Error Xcode 6.2 using Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835490/expected-declaration-error-xcode-6-2-using-swift)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Please use this code:

**Swift 5.0**,
**Swift 4.0** And
**Swift 3.0**

```
let DocumentDirectory = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
let DirPath = DocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("FOLDER_NAME")
do
{
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: DirPath!.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
}
catch let error as NSError
{
    print("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
}
print("Dir Path = \(DirPath!)")
```

Comment: from log looks like it creates directory , How to access it from GUI to store a file or pic captured by scanner ?

Comment: Do add `Supports opening documents in place` in info plist

Comment: you can use initializer that supports url directly (avoiding force unwrap):
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

Comment: also check if directory exist before creating new:  
      if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {}

Answer (score 45):

For **Swift 4.0** 
Please use this

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if let tDocumentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let filePath =  tDocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(FOLDER_NAME)") 
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {
            do {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: filePath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                NSLog("Couldn't create document directory")
            }
        }
        NSLog("Document directory is \(filePath)")
    }
```

Comment: I got ` Cannot invoke 'appendingPathComponent' with no arguments`

Answer (score 24):

For **Swift 4.0**, I created the following extension off of `URL` that allows for the creation of a folder off of the documents directory within the application.

```
import Foundation

extension URL {
    static func createFolder(folderName: String) -> URL? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        // Get document directory for device, this should succeed
        if let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                    in: .userDomainMask).first {
            // Construct a URL with desired folder name
            let folderURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(folderName)
            // If folder URL does not exist, create it
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: folderURL.path) {
                do {
                    // Attempt to create folder
                    try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: folderURL.path,
                                                    withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                                    attributes: nil)
                } catch {
                    // Creation failed. Print error & return nil
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return nil
                }
            }
            // Folder either exists, or was created. Return URL
            return folderURL
        }
        // Will only be called if document directory not found
        return nil
    }
}
```

If the desired folder does not exist, it will create it. Then, assuming the folder exists, it returns the `URL` back to the user. Otherwise, if it fails, then `nil` is returned.

For example, to create the folder "MyStuff", you would call it like this:

```
let myStuffURL = URL.createFolder(folderName: "MyStuff")
```

This would return:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4DE0A1C0-8629-47C9-87D7-C2B4F3A16D24/Documents/MyStuff/

You can also create nested folders with the following:

```
let myStuffHereURL = URL.createFolder(folderName: "My/Stuff/Here")
```

Which gives you:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4DE0A1C0-8629-47C9-87D7-C2B4F3A16D24/Documents/My/Stuff/Here/

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this because you are assigning value to `newDir` instance at wrong place.

I wrote your code in `viewDidLoad` and it works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: I have created an action in view controller with a button called 'create directory.' The code works without any error and creates a directory at file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EB48367A-80E3-4714-955D-3284E4D28F0A/Documents/data/.             How do i access this directory and save files to it via GUI(Main.storyboard). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 5 and up Version

```
let documentDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let directoryURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("FolderName", isDirectory: true)
        
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: directoryURL.path) {
             print(directoryURL.path)
        } else {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: directoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                print(directoryURL.path)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Directory

```
private let fileManager = FileManager.default

func createDirectory(atURL url:URL,withFolderName folderName:String)->Bool{
    do{
        let folderURL = url.appendingPathComponent(folderName, conformingTo: .folder)
        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: false)
        print("Directory Created!")
        return true
    }catch(let creationError){
        print("Error while creating Directory. \(creationError)")
    }
    return false
}

func getDownloadsDirectoryURL()->URL{
    return fileManager.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
}
```