# Naming of folder in documents directory Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm using the following code (lifted from another answer) to create a folder in the documents directory (my app requires an export of a file). I'm trying to name this folder but the folder is creating with the name of the Xcode project rather than the name I have specified :

```
func createFileDirectory() {
    let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])

//set the name of the new folder
    let folderPath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("MY NAME HERE")
    do
    {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: folderPath!.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

So when the user is able to save to files, it should allow them to save to a folder called "MY FOLDER HERE" but it just creates a folder with the name of the Xcode project ("MY_PROJECT")

I can't find any other answers other than the one that gave me the answer in the first place [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162610/create-directory-in-swift-3-0)

I can't see where I'm doing anything wrong? It's creating **a** folder it's just ignoring the name?

**UPDATE**

Following answers I've updated to the URL API method and removed spaces from the target folder name but still getting the wrong folder name (of the project name)

updated code:

```
func createFileDirectory() {
    let documentsURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

    //set the name of the new folder
    let folderURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("FirstDraft")
    do
    {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `URL` instead of `NSURL`.

Comment: I’d suggest you edit your code in your question to `print(folderURL)` and also show us what the `folderURL` is. This code, from vadian, is correct. When I run this on a simulator, I see `/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/76F6650B-...-A43327F2A267/data/Containers/Data/Application/3F1DCBEE-...-EA7F58957EEC/Documents/FirstDraft`, which is correct.

Comment: Thanks I’ll do this when I can get back to the computer - are you able to go to Files and see if the name is reflected in the folder displayed there also?

Comment: this works now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the URL related API. It's much more reliable

```
func createFileDirectory() {
    let documentsURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)

    //set the name of the new folder
    let folderURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("MY NAME HERE")
    do
    {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks - this isn't working for me in simulator but i'll try on a real device soon – nc14 just now

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working on a real device either - it's just showing the folder name as the name of the project still

Comment: "Application supports iTunes file sharing" set to YES