# NumberFormatter can only be written in closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures, number-formatting

Following along in the *The Big Nerd Ranch Guide* book I came across a passage in one of the chapters that requires you to create an instance of a `NumberFormatter`. Everything works as expected but I noticed that the formatter is created using a `closure` as:

```
class ConversionViewController: UIViewController {
    let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let nf = NumberFormatter()

        nf.numberStyle = .decimal
        nf.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        nf.maximumFractionDigits = 1

        return nf
    }()

    func updateCelsiusLabel() {
        if let celsiusValue = celsiusValue {
             celsiusLabel.text = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: celsiusValue.value))
        } else {
            celsiusLabel.text = "???"
        }
    }
}
```

Just out of curiosity I tried creating this formatter outside of the closure like:

```
let nf = NumberFormatter()

nf.numberStyle = .decimal
nf.minimumFractionDigits = 0
nf.maximumFractionDigits = 1
```

But got the error saying

> Expected declaration

My questions are:

1. Why can't `NumberFormatters` be created outside a closure in this
   case?
2. What do the parenthesis `()` represent at the end of the
   closure? My guess is that it's self invoking but why does it need to be?

Up to this point I've never seen closures written in this way. Is there anything in the Apple docs that explain this?

Comment: Can you share more code where you creating formatter?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835490/expected-declaration-error-using-swift/29835573#29835573

Comment: @AbhishekJain I updated my question. Let me know if that's enough.

Comment: Creating NumberFormatter outside of the closure never gives error. Share code where you got error?

Comment: I updated my question once again to show that I'm attempting this in a `UIViewController` instance.

Comment: Short answer #1: It is forbidden to use code which refers to `self` on the top level of a **class** for initialization reasons.

Comment: @ dfri I only updated my question for further clarification for those who asked for more info in the comments above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NumberFormatter` as well as the closure instantiation is a red herring here: the problem is that you're trying to change an instance property (`nf`) directly in the scope of a type declaration (although you've failed to show us that all your code is indeed enclosed inside the scope of a type definition), but outside the scope of e.g. an instance function or an initializer.

Compare with:

```
struct Foo {
    var a = 1
    a = 2 // Error: expected declaration
}
```

A compiling example would be:

```
struct Foo {
    var a = 1
    mutating func mutateMe() {
        a = 2 // OK
    }
}
```

As for you question **2)**: the parantheses `()` is used to perform a once-only invokation of the closure, where the return of the closure is used to instantiate `nf`. If you didn't invoke it, then `nf` would be a closure of type `() -> NumberFormatter` rather than an actual instance of `NumberFormatter`. Compare with:

```
struct Foo {
    let a: Int = { 
        var a = 1
        a = 2
        return a
    }() // instantiate 'a' of Foo by _once-only 
        // invoking a specified closure_.
}
```

Compare to the same concept but outside of a type declaration/definition:

```
// this is a closure
let aClosure: () -> Int = { _ in return 42 }

// this is an invokation of a closure
// (discarding the result)
_ = aClosure()

// this is also an invokation of a closure
let num = { _ in return 42 }() // 'num' inferred to Int
```

Comment: I guess my only question at the moment is the concept of type annotation in this case. Are variables in Swift smart enough to determine that the **return value** within the closure will be its value?

Answer (score 1):

**First Answer:** I test your code snippet in Playground and it does not show any error. I think you may do something wrong which is not related to `NumberFormatter`.

```
let nf = NumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = .decimal
nf.minimumFractionDigits = 0
nf.maximumFractionDigits = 1
```

**Second Answer:** The closure’s end curly brace tells Swift to execute the closure immediately. If you omit these parentheses, you are trying to assign the closure itself to the property, and not the return value of the closure. [App Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

Comment: Obviously the OP uses a class. The behavior of a class and a Playground is completely different regarding question #1.

Answer (score 0):

`nf` in this case is an instance property. Which itself turns out to be a class having its own property. When you declare

```
let nf = NumberFormatter()
```

nf is there for you but with default properties. And you can not set its property in declaration. You will get this error.

[image]