# Error when creating simple dictionary with Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm learning SpriteKit, and trying to create a simple dictionary, that is, this simple dictionary:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    let someDic = ["a":1, "b":2, "c":3]
    print(someDic)
```

I constantly end up with the following error message:

> Cannot find type 'someDic' in scope

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The print statement must be inside some *method* of that class. Compare this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29835490/1187415.

Comment: The code you posted would not compile. You can't put executable code like your print statement outside of a function. You'll have to create an actual example of the problem your'e seeing in order for us to be able to help you sort it out.

Comment: Thanks, this was it, it had to bee in a !unction...

Comment: See my answer then

Comment: It's been seen and accepted... Thanks again! I come from Python and find myself lost in the simplest problems, so I appreciate the help

Comment: I learned Swift by reading Apple's Swift iBook. It teaches you programming from the beginning using Swift as the language. The whole first half of the book is a tutorial, and the 2nd half is a reference. You might want to try it. (It has the advantage of being free.) I have a background with compiled languages in the C/C++ family, so Swift wasn't a big leap for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted won't compile. The print statement has to be inside a function.

I would expect the error "Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration".

If you create a command line tool, this code WOULD compile and run:

```
import Foundation

class Foo {
    
    let someDic = ["a":1, "b":2, "c":3]
    func someFunc() {
        print(someDic)
    }
}

let aFoo = Foo()
aFoo.someFunc()
```