# Im trying to save coins in my game but it gives me an error saying Expected declaration

Tags: swift

i tried to save use this to save my coins but i get an error saying expected declaration

`if(coins > 0) { UserDefaults.setInteger(coins, forKey: "coinScore") }`

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: [Expected Declaration Error using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835490/expected-declaration-error-using-swift)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift the type of the data being saved to user defaults is determined by the value. There is no `setInteger` method. And you need to use the `standard` property to get the user defaults instance.

Assuming `coins` is an integer, this should work:

```
if coins > 0 { UserDefaults.standard.set(coins, forKey: "coinScore") }
```

(I also removed the parenthesis around the condition as this style is the preferred Swift way.)